# Single SQL to retrieve different information from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have this query which retrives 10 ( $limited ) queries from MySQL ,

```
"SELECT content.loc,content.id,content.title,
voting_count.up,voting_count.down 
FROM 
content,voting_count 
WHERE names.id = voting_count.unique_content_id 
ORDER BY content.id DESC $limit"
```

This query did great for posts that were allready in database and had votes , however new posts won't show. 
Vote row is "inserted" first time someone votes on post. I guess that the reason why they won't be listed as there is no unique_content_id to connect to.

---

If i change query into this :

```
"SELECT content.loc,content.id,content.title
FROM 
content
ORDER BY content.id DESC $limit"
```

it works , but i can't access voting_count.up & voting_count.down rows. 
How could i access both information in single query ? Is it doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some data might not exist in one of the tables, instead of using `INNER JOIN` you should use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT content.loc,content.id,content.title,
   -- USE function COALSESCE will show 0 if there are no 
   -- related records in table voting_count
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) as votes_up,  
    COALSESCE(voting_count.down, 0) as voted_down
FROM content LEFT JOIN voting_count 
    ON content.id = voting_count.unique_content_id 
ORDER BY content.id DESC
```

Comment: This works better then i expected , thank you for your time answering.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else above mentioned, what is `names.id`? However, perhaps the following might be of use assuming the join should have been from `content.id` to `voting_count.unique_content_id`:

```
$sql="select 
    c.`loc`,c.`id`, c.`title`, 
    case
        when v.`up` is null then
            0
        else
            v.`up`
    end as 'up',
    case
        when v.`down` is null then
            0
        else
            v.`down`
    end as 'down'
    from `content` c 
    left outer join `voting_count` v on v.`unique_content_id`=c.`id`
    order by c.`id` desc {$limit}";
```

Comment: Thank for your time asnwering.