# How should i - retrieve correct information from two tables with $id passed by php

Tags: php, mysql

I have single page , that contains content body , content name and content id from one table. It also contains votes from second table that are linked by `voting_count.unique_content_id` with `content.id`. 
voting_count table doesnt have primary key and row is first inserted (initialized) when someone votes until then there is no record for it.

`$id` variable is from `PHP $_GET['id']` as in address bar link
ex: `index.php?id=$id`

This query retrives correct content , but it also retrieves 1st row in voting_count. On every "single" page.

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON content.id = '$id' 
LIMIT 1
```

Then i tried switching places like this :

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON voting_count.unique_content_id = '$id' 
LIMIT 1
```

This will retrieve correct votes , but it will always retrieve 1st row from content table.

Next i tried this :

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
WHERE content.id = '$id' 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON content.id = voting_count.unique_content_id    
LIMIT 1
```

Code above, doesnt even render page ,as i am suspecting that query is invalid.

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON content.id = voting_count.unique_content_id
WHERE voting_count.unique_content_id = '$id'
LIMIT 1
```

The above query will retrieve correct information , but only on content that has votes, otherwise it will do 404.

My question is , how can i retrieve correct `voting_count.unique_content_id` & `content.id` which are linked to `$id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the join operator in the wrong way:

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON content.id = '$id' 
LIMIT 1
```

is wrong because the ON clause should just tell mySql what are the columns in the joined table that store the same information. Then you should use WHERe clause to say what is the joined value to look for.
The query should look like:

```
SELECT content.id,content.loc,content.title,
    COALESCE(voting_count.up, 0) AS vote_up,
    COALESCE(voting_count.down, 0) AS vote_down
FROM content 
LEFT JOIN voting_count ON content.id = unique_content_id
WHERE content.id = '$id' 
LIMIT 1
```

I also have some doubts if you are using the right query as I see a left join and the coalesce command. If you can show us an example of data in the two tables and the expected result (better in a sqlfiddle) we can help you to build a smarter query

Comment: Thank you , i understand now that was clear explanation.

Comment: About right query part : 
i asked similiar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184900/single-sql-to-retrieve-different-information-from-different-tables
And from there i got idea of coalesce to subtitue 0 for rows that do not exist in database.
I am sorry , i am not that versed in mysql , i am just learning. Anyway 
voting_count table contains 3 rows
unique_content_id (int 11) , up(int 4) , down(int 4)

unique_content_id is inserted with whatever selection user makes (up) or (down) into voting_count. In PHP i have IF condition to check if that rows exist.If it does then only

Comment: update is applied on whatever selection user makes UP or DOWN.

Comment: Ok, I see that there is a logic behind it (that was not clear from this question). Then keep going with this logic in my own opinion :)